# Python 2D Sprite Animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, pygame

I'm trying to animate a sprite using a loop such that each time the loop runs through the position number for an image in an array increases by one. I keep getting "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Antic' referenced before assignment". There is

```
    Antic = 0
Antic = int(Antic)
# Global constants
StAnmtn = ["Images/PlayerVampireStanding1.png", " 
Images/PlayerVampireStanding2.png", 
"Images/PlayerVampireStanding3.png","Images/PlayerVampireStanding4.png", 
"Images/PlayerVampireStanding5.png", "Images/PlayerVampireStanding6.png", 
"Images/PlayerVampireStanding7.png", "Images/PlayerVampireStanding8.png"]
```

`
at the start and

```
    def main():
    """ Main Program """
    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()     # creates clock to limit frames per 
    second

    FPS = 60  # sets max speed of min loop

    SCREENSIZE = SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT = 1300, 700  # sets size of 
    screen/window
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE)  # creates window and game 
    screen

    pygame.display.set_caption("Count Acheron")

    # Create the player
    player = Player()

    # Create all the levels
    level_list = []
    level_list.append( Level_01(player) )

    # Set the current level
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    player.rect.x = 340
    player.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)

    # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False

    # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    while not done:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.go_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.jump()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.change_x < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.change_x > 0:
                    player.stop()  

        if Antic > 6:
            Antic = 0
        else:
            Antic += 1
        # Update the player.
        active_sprite_list.update()

        # Update items in the level
        current_level.update()

        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT
        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)

        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

        # Limit to 60 frames per second
        clock.tick(60)

        # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
        pygame.display.flip()
        # Be IDLE friendly. If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
        # on exit.
        pygame.quit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

as the loop. What it doesn't seem to like is the snippet of code

```
    if Antic > 6:
        Antic = 0
    else:
        Antic += 1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Ah ok, just seen the tag

Comment: Now I'm having a problem with the variable Antic where it doesn't seem to be finding the file from the array based on the value of Antic. I think it's because you can't use variables in the [] of an array but I don't know of any functional alternatives ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to globalise the function ("global Antic" in the main loop)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've never used pygame's sprite module.

```
import pygame

class character:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sprites = [pygame.image.load("img1.png"), pygame.image.load("img2.png")]
        self.frame = 0

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.sprites[self.frame], (self.x, self.y))
        self.frame += 1
        if self.frame > len(self.sprites) - 1: self.frame = 0

pygame.init()
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

c = character(640, 360)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()

    c.draw(DS)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
    DS.fill((0, 0, 0))
```